# How to call cb function after async function finished in loopback 3

Tags: asynchronous, loopbackjs

I worked at a loopback project.
Here I'm making extended api in the model.
There are many async functions.
I want to call cb function after all async functions called.
Anyone have idea to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `async.parallel` that run function parallel and return final results.

**Below example help you:**

```
var async = require('async')


  function functionName(parameter, cb) {
        async.parallel([
          function(callback) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                  callback(null, 'one');
              }, 200);
          },
          function(callback) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                  callback(null, 'two');
              }, 100);
          }
      ],
      // optional callback
      function(err, results) {
          // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
          // the second function had a shorter timeout.
          if (error) {
            logger.error("ERROR FIRST SUBSCRIPTION > ", error);
            cb(error);
            return;
        }
        cb(null, {
            success: true
        });
      });
};
```

reference Link: [async](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Loopback 3 supports promise callbacks. Just return promise

for example:

```
User.findUserByName = function(name, req, res, cb) {
   return User.find({filter: {where: {name: name}}).then(function(result){
         //make antoher calls
         return result
   })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The basics of async / await can be found here :
[MDN async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Therefore, you should do something like :

```
function fct1(a) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do something
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(a + 1);
    }, 500);
  });
}
function fct2(a) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do something else
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(a + 1);
    }, 500);
  })
}

async function mainFct(cb) { 
  const a = 0;
  const b = await fct1(a);
  const c = await fct2(b); // won't be executed until fct1 has finished
  cb(c);                   // won't be executed until fct2 has finished
}

mainFct((result) => {
  console.log(result);     // prints 2
});
```

I hope it helps...